# PrimeFaces color picker popup not showing up at the right place

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces's color picker (the popup version).  However, when I click on the icon to bring up the color picker, it shows up below all my other content (below the submit button and not below the icon like it's supposed to do).  I have tried removing my css and moving everything around to no avail.  The color picker is in a `<h:form>`, a `<div>`, and a `<h:panelGrid>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<title>Index</title>
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div class="title"> <h1> Testing </h1> </div>
<br />

<h:form>
<div class="forms">
<h:messages />
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="column1Class column2Class" cellpadding="10">
    <h:outputText value="Test1 " />
    <h:inputText value="#{userConfig.test1}" />

    <h:outputText value="ColorInline1 " />
    <p:colorPicker value="#{userConfig.colorInline1}" mode="inline"/> 

    <h:outputText value="ColorInline2: " />
    <p:colorPicker value="#{userConfig.colorInline2}" mode="inline"/> 

    <h:outputText value="ColorPopup " />
    <p:colorPicker value="#{userConfig.colorPopup}" />

    <h:outputText value="Test2" />
    <h:inputText value="#{userConfig.test2}" />

</h:panelGrid>
    <br />
    <p:commandButton action="newValsIndex" value="Submit" ajax="false">   </p:commandButton>
</div>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the code. Makes it much easier to help you. I assume its showing up at the right place in the primefaces showcase. So it is probable that something is "disarranged" in your code. But without seeing it it s hard to help you...

Comment: Good point. I've edited my post with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem easily, actually, in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/colorPicker.jsf), it is working properly. The major difference is that you have less components. Testing their code alone in an empty page generate theses css/javascript includes :

```
<link href="/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jspx?ln=primefaces-aristo" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jspx?ln=primefaces" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/javax.faces.resource/colorpicker/colorpicker.css.jspx?ln=primefaces" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jspx?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.jspx?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/javax.faces.resource/colorpicker/colorpicker.js.jspx?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.jspx?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript">
```

As soon as you cleanup the example and keep only the `p:colorPicker`, the last one is missing. This looks like a PrimeFaces bug, you can work arround by adding this line in your `h:head` :

```
<h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" library="primefaces" />
```

Comment: That worked beautifully.  Now all I need to do is figure out how to change the background color of the colorpicker...
Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2471366 You will simply have to overload the class `.ui-colorpicker-container` with a new `background: ...` because it is currently using an image.